# Reshape a weird wide format to long in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset in this fashion. Note that `var2` is `character`

```
var1 var2
a    "b:2, d:4"
b    "a:1, b:3, c:4, d:2"
c    "a:3"
d    "b:2, d:4, a:1"
```

and I want to reshape it into the long format

```
var1 var2 value
a    b    2
a    d    4
b    a    1
b    b    3
...
d    d    4
d    a    1
```

I'm tempted to iterate over the rows but speed is a concern for me. What is the more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: Please add you dataset using `dput()`.

Comment: I think you want to do this in 2 steps: 1) split the string in column 2 into key-value pairs as 2 new columns, then 2) convert wide to long format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows` to get data in different rows splitting on comma (`,`) and `separate` to get data in different column splitting on colon (`:`).

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate_rows(var2, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  separate(var2, c('var2', 'value'), sep = ':', convert = TRUE)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   var1  var2  value
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 a     b         2
# 2 a     d         4
# 3 b     a         1
# 4 b     b         3
# 5 b     c         4
# 6 b     d         2
# 7 c     a         3
# 8 d     b         2
# 9 d     d         4
#10 d     a         1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), var2 = c("b:2, d:4", 
"a:1, b:3, c:4, d:2", "a:3", "b:2, d:4, a:1")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Wow this is immensely helpful! Thank you!